# Gradle: disable autodownloading dependencies

Tags: gradle

I created a Gradle project in Eclipse, and the following `build.gradle` was created.

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.18'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Afterwards, the `slf4j` module was downloaded and cached in `~/.gradle`.

But I didn't want it!! My Linux distribution contains `slf4j` in the repositories, so I'd rather use `pacman`/`apt-get`/etc. to install the needed module.

I'd rather Gradle errored out that the module is missing, or download the needed modules only if a flag is specified.

How can I stop Gradle from being overzealous?

Comment: If you don't want to download anything from jcenter, then don't add jcenter as a repository. If you don't define any repository, gradle won't download anything. But you'll have to download and handle your dependencies manually, and jcenter/Maven central are the best place to find such Java dependencies. Using apt to do that is a horrible idea.

Comment: Why a horrible idea? My distribution's package manager does a better job than me at remembering, what was installed, where it resides, what takes most space.

Comment: apt is useful to handle native executable packages of a Linux machine that uses apt. That's not what you're doing here. You're trying to handle the dependencies of a Java project. And that's what a Java dependency management tool like gradle is for. The whole point of a build tool like gradle is that anyone should be able to get the sources of your project (on Windows, on a Mac, on any Linux flavor), execute `gradlew build`, and have the dependencies downloaded and the project built.

Comment: Ok, so I could configure my local Gradle installation to ask me before downloading, and everyone else could `gradlew build`. I do have a local gradle install, this would then be pointless too since `gradlew` downloads the `gradle` binary. - it's what `gradlew` is for - do a build where you know nothing about the system. But when I have a total control above the system...

Comment: No, that's not only what gradlew is for. gradlew is there in order for anyone to get the sources of your project, type gradlew, use the correct version of gradle and download it if necessary. If you decide to switch from gradle 2.12 to gradle 2.13, you commit the change, and every developer will then automatically use the the 2.13 version. You seem to reason as if disks had 250 MBs available and you had to save as much disk space as possible. That's not the case. Disks are large and cheap. Having two versions of gradle or two versions of slf4j.jar on a developer machine is normal and expected.

Comment: Ok, and how could I set the classpath to make Gradle recognize my system-wide JUnit if the needed version is installed? [i.e. if there's no needed JUnit in `/usr/share/java`, let it download the jcentral version] (for all projects, so something like `gradle.properties` or `init.gradle`)

Comment: You can point to a specific file on your disk, making the build work only on your machine, and making all your projects tightly coupled to that single version of JUnit: two situations that you should really, really avoid. Why don't you do it the right, standard way, let gradle handle its own cache of dependencies, download them if not already in its cache, and make each project self-contained, and independent from other projects that might have different dependency requirements? You're shooting yourself in the foot. Gradle works the way it works because it capitalizes on best practices.

Comment: But why can't I specify in my local configuration file, that I'd like gradle to recognize all jars `/usr/share/java`, and use them if needed? And on other machines the file would be absent, so it would all work the standard way. If all this configuration resides in my `$HOME`, then it's all specific to me. In C++ I'd simply set include path to some directory.

I simply dislike the way gradle works; it's utterly against the KISS principle that apps (including OSes) do things they aren't explicitly asked to.

Comment: Because a jar file is not sufficient to know what library it is, which version of the library it contains, which repo it comes from. All these metadata are needed by gradle, and stored in the gradle cache. The Java ecosystem has at least acknowledged that many Java programs can run/be developed in parallel on a single machine, that all machines don't run your preferred linux flavor, and could all need a **different** version of the same library. Trying to impose the same library version to all Java programs justwon't work.